# When an Oracle Scheduled Job is Enabled, is it run in separate session?

Tags: oracle, oracle11gr2

I've recently been learning to use Oracle's scheduler to run jobs asynchronously.

I'm trying to build jobs that only run once and then are automatically dropped.

The way I've accomplished this is to set the MAX_RUNS attribute of a job to 1 and for the AUTO_DROP attribute to be set to TRUE.

All my jobs are DISABLED by default as I only kick them off manually.

I noticed that the jobs were not being dropped and this [Ask Tom thread](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:::NO:RP:P11_QUESTION_ID:9527303800346678598) explained why.

Thus I must enable my jobs first before running them if they are to be dropped automatically.

However when a job is enabled it is scheduled immediately.

My question is:

When a scheduled job is enabled, and thus immediately scheduled, does it execute in a separate session?

I am needing the jobs to all be scheduled asynchronously and thus I am hoping to achieve the same behavior as:

```
DBMS_SCHEDULER.RUN_JOB(V_JOB_NAME, FALSE);
```

FALSE indicating asynchronous scheduling of the job in a separate session.

I am fine with the approach of enabling a job and having it immediately scheduled, as long as it's asynchronous in a separate session.

Alternatively, if there was a way to enforce that a job is NOT scheduled when it is enabled, that would work as well.

I am currently on Oracle 11gR2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found that by setting the START_DATE of a new job to a future date and the REPEAT_INTERVAL to something like 'FREQ=YEARLY' then the job will not run immediately when it is enabled.

While not ideal, this will allow for the job to be dropped when run manually via the DBMS_SCEHDULER.RUN_JOB(V_JOB_NAME, FALSE); command.

However this does imply that the job is scheduled to run at some point in the future. So just don't forget to run it manually. That's fine in my case since everything is happening in a single call, but good to call out.

Answer (score 0):

If I had a bunch of asynchronous 1-time jobs that needed to be run, I would seriously consider using the old `dbms_job` package to do my scheduling rather than `dbms_scheduler`.  Then you're just doing something like this

```
declare
  l_jobno pls_integer;
begin
  dbms_job.submit( l_jobno,
                   '<<what you want the job to do>>',
                   sysdate );
end;
/
```

This will cause a new session to be opened as soon as you commit the `submit` that runs whatever code you specified. It'll run once and then get removed from `dba_jobs`.

Alternatively, I'd try to re-architect the system so that there is a background "widget processor" job that runs every few minutes, reads a table to determine what widgets need to be processed, and processes those widgets.  That probably makes more sense than spawning a separate job to process each widget.

`dbms_scheduler` is wonderful when you want to have more sophisticated processing where one job depends on another and jobs get started based on events.  But old-school `dba_jobs` can be really handy when you just need a very lightweight framework for very simple jobs.

Comment: Thanks Justin, that makes a lot of sense. My use case is primarily dynamic data extraction. Each scheduled job simply calls a program with 2 arguments, function name and customer id. The job executes the function to extract the data and writes the data out to a file. There are a few other steps, but that's the main piece. Perhaps using standard jobs are an easier approach. I plan on building more control around the process, so failed jobs can be restarted, etc. and I think that's only available on scheduled jobs? I really appreciate your insight, thanks again!

Comment: @rcurrie - I would much rather have a table with two columns named something like `customer_to_extract` that your code writes a row to and then a single customer extraction job that runs every n minutes and processes everything in that table than to have a bunch of stand-alone jobs running.  That tends to make it much easier to build in job control (i.e. try to process a row twice, if it fails, write it to a separate table of problem extracts that someone can monitor, it's easy to write a report that shows the extracts that are currently in the queue, etc.)

Comment: That is a great approach as well. The prior process was entirely synchronous (240+ function executions per customer) and I am trying to achieve better performance by kicking off the jobs for a customer asynchronously. Each function is responsible for a single data element, thus if 5 customers need processing, that would be 1,200 jobs running. If a single job for a customer fails I'd like to be able to re-run just that one job, versus everything. Hopefully that makes sense.

Comment: @rcurrie - I would definitely not want to have 1200 separate jobs running.  I'd much rather have a single job that did the data extraction (maybe a few of them if you need more threads to keep up) that knew how to mark a row in the `customer_to_extract` table as failing.  It's much easier to query that, fix whatever is failing, and then mark the row to try again.

Comment: Thanks again for the insight, I'll definitely re-evaluate the process. I'm having a hard time understanding how to achieve higher throughput with a smaller number of jobs running. If the jobs are calling functions to execute queries and write out data, if only 1 job is responsible for that how could many function calls be made at the same time?